# Is this particular encryption algorithm secure?

Tags: encryption, security-definition

Suppose that $(\mathrm{Gen},\mathrm{Enc},\mathrm{Dec})$ is a secure encryption scheme. Encryption scheme is ***secure*** if for any two sequences $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}},\{b_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of messages such that $|a_{n}|=|b_{n}| = p(n)$ $\mathrm{Enc}(k,a_{n})$ and $\mathrm{Enc}(k,b_{n})$ are computationally indistinguishable.

Define $\mathrm{Enc}'(k,m) = (\mathrm{Enc}(k,m),1^{u})$, where $u$ stands for number of $1$'s in $m$ (if there are no $1$'s, then just $\mathrm{Enc}(k,m)$), and $(s_{1},s_{2})$ is a concatenation of $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$.

Is $\mathrm{Enc}'$ (always) a secure encryption algorithm?

One can take $a_{n} = 0^{n}$ and $b_{n} = 0^{n-1}1$, then $\mathrm{Enc}'(k,0^{n}) = \mathrm{Enc}(k,0^{n})$ and $\mathrm{Enc}'(k,0^{n-1}1) = (\mathrm{Enc}(k,0^{n-1}1),1)$ and thus $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ have different lengths. Is this right? Should $\mathrm{Enc}$ algorithm return the same length for an input of given length?

Comment: Enc' doesn't seem reversible even.

Comment: The attack has good ideas, but is currently at odds with the definition of $Enc'$. As said before, $Enc'$ doesn't guarantee correctness. To be fair, there are such schemes but, it's more likely here that the question is ill-posed.